# Allocating non-contiguous free space to an existing partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted, xubuntu

[image]
[image: gparted screenshot 1]

I can't figure out how to add all the "/dev/sda3" space to my /dev/sda1/ .. I tried everything, but /dev/sda1/ can't go over 5.26GB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, gparted does not support online resizing of partitions. Thus, if you don't have advanced knowledge of Linux, you should boot from a Linux CD (e.g. the Ubuntu install CD/USB) and run gparted from there.

The easiest way then is to move the swap partition out of the way:

- right-click on /dev/sda5, Select **swapoff** (if applicable)
- delete /dev/sda5 (it doesn't contain any data, so don't worry)
- delete /dev/sda2
- re-create /dev/sda2 using right-click->New

  - set the "Size" to 1792 MB, the "Free space following" to 0 and the "Create as" to "Extended Partition"
- then, re-create /dev/sda5 inside /dev/sda2

  - set "Size" to the maximum available (~1792MB) and set the "File System" to "linux-swap".
- Finally, you can right-click on /dev/sda1, select "Resize/Move" and resize it

After you've rebooted, you should also update the UUID of the new swap partition. Do this:

```
sudo swapoff /dev/sda5 # this might give an error message which you can ignore
sudo mkswap -U`grep -E '^UUID.+swap\W+sw' /etc/fstab | cut -d= -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1` /dev/sda5
```

It should return `Setting up swapspace ...` and some numbers, and a UUID.
Then you can re-enable the swap:

```
sudo swapon -a
```

Comment: All worked but the last bit with the UUID is it necessary? I'm on a VM. `g@g-ubuntu-64:~ $ sudo swapoff /dev/sda5
swapoff: /dev/sda5: swapoff failed: Invalid argument`

Comment: The `swapoff` command may indeed fail, that's not a problem. If you don't update the UUID, you won't have any swap space, which can cause problems. Also, hibernation will not work - I don't know if it's relevant for you or if hibernation would work in VM in the first place.

Comment: I have an annoying message at boot, I'd like to have swap, what's the alternative to the swapoff command?

Comment: Good answer, that's what I would do too. But, excuse me for asking, what's the point in having the swap inside an extended partition that only contains it and nothing more?

Answer (score 3):

I am not 100% sure I remember exactly, but try first to move the `swap` partition so that the unallocated space is shown next to `sda1`, then it should be possible to enlarge that partition.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `/dev/sda2` or a `swap` partition immediately after `/dev/sda1`, then you'll need to shrink and move them to the right so the free space is shown between `/dev/sda1` and the other partitions.

Just note that this can take, for a 1TB HDD, over 10 hours to complete if there is a lot of data.