# Merge two unadjacent partitions

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, merge

I have three partitions on my drive, arranged something like the following:

```
 ___________
| 1 |  2 | 3|
-------------
```

I wish to merge partitions 1 and 3.

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to manually "slide" partition 2 over to partition 3, and then merge the newly open space where partition 2 used to be?

**Note:** I do not have the space to copy partition 2 to partition 3 (2 is 200GB and 3 is 65GB).

Comment: [Allocating non-contiguous free space to an existing partition](http://superuser.com/q/593828)

Comment: @Sathya, I can't delete the data in the middle (or rather, I don't want to)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you may be able to do it if the disks are dynamic from Disk Management.  However, you can just use  [Gnome Partition Editor](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).  It will allow you to move partitions around on the disk, regardless of type.

Comment: Is there a way for it to be smart about it and simply move the first ~65GB ish around, and then change the MFT accordingly?

Comment: Im not following what you are asking.  However, I would just suggest burning the GPE ISO and booting off it.  Its fairly intuitive.  You can play around with the partitions, so you can see what it will do.  However, it wont actually *do* anything until your commit the changes.

Comment: option #1 (naive): copy all 200GB over to partially overlap with partition #2, and fill #3.
option #2 (optimized): copy over the first 65GB or so to partition #3, re-write the MFT to refer to the new locations of those files (or even file fragments).

The difference is between a 65GB copy, and a 200GB copy

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can't have a partition with an "hole". That's because partitions were useful mainly to have a faster access to files.